# Docker-compose won't start MySQL if I define a volume

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a volume for my MySQL container so the data can persist. So in my docker-compose, I created a volume in which the data will be stored.

Here's my docker-compose :

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: portfolio
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: blog
      DB_USERNAME: blog
      DB_PASSWORD: ...
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blog
      MYSQL_USER: blog
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ...
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ...
    volumes:
      - "./db:/var/lib/mysql"
```

The volume is defined at the end of the file. Unfortunately, that's not working. If I do a `docker container ls` it only shows the portfolio container, and if I do a `docker container ls -a` it does show my the container for MySQL, but it says it has "exited" right after I did the `docker-compose up -d`, so apparently it was started but then immediately crashed or something.

If I remove the last 2 lines related to the MySQL volume, it works fine. My containers are both up and the app works normally. So basically what causes the container to crash is the volume, so maybe I didn't define it correctly. What do you think ?

Comment: Is the `./db` directory empty?  Does MySQL say anything when you start it up with the volume attached?

Comment: The db directory is indeed empty, but neither MySQL nor Docker say anything when I do the docker-compose up. By the way, I tried to use MySQL 8.0 this time but the result is the same. Of course I get an error with PHP/PDO when I try to go to the application, since the MySQL container isn't up.

Comment: Oops my bad, MySQL does give me an error when I do docker-compose up. It seems to be related to permissions : "Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)"

Comment: Is it intended that one time you specify your volume with quotation marks and another time you dont?

Comment: Originally I didn't use quotation marks, but I wanted to try it with, but it didn't change anything to the problem.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Did you try running `chmod 777 db` before running the stack? Also it’s much better to use named volumes instead, it’s easier to maintain.

Comment: I experience the same problem. What's the solution to this?

Comment: Using the quoted marks worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I found on my Windows system that although my local volume (i.e ./db) looked empty it really wasn't. I wound up running `ls -la` from a bash shell on the same folder it showed a .sock file in it. Once I removed (`rm -f *.sock`) that and ran `docker-compose up --build` it seemed to mount the volume properly